# Can I run sbt new with a local template (not GitHub)?

Tags: scala, sbt, giter8

I work in a secure environment where developers are not allowed to git-clone from GitHub, or any other external repos.

I was able to download a g8 template (play-scala-seed) from GitHub as a zip file and I've unzipped it to a local folder. Can I use that local directory instead of a git repo?

My first attempt at this failed:

```
> dir .\play-scala-seed
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is A074-A016

 Directory of C:\workspace\play-scala-seed

03/22/2018  11:03 AM    <DIR>          .
03/22/2018  11:03 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/22/2018  11:01 AM    <DIR>          project
03/22/2018  10:57 AM    <DIR>          src
03/22/2018  11:03 AM    <DIR>          target
03/22/2018  10:57 AM                70 .gitignore
03/22/2018  10:57 AM               509 .travis.yml
03/22/2018  10:57 AM               453 build.sbt
03/22/2018  10:57 AM               439 LICENSE
03/22/2018  10:57 AM             1,166 README.md
               5 File(s)          2,637 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  220,172,980,224 bytes free
```

Even though I'm sure the template exists and in in a directory called "play-scala-seed", it's not accepted by the SBT new command:

```
> sbt new .\play-scala-seed
Template not found for: .\play-scala-seed
```

So how can I make sbt new use a local directory for a g8 template?

I'm running Windows (if that matters!)

Comment: this page explain how testing giter8 templates locally. It could be helpfull for you : http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/testing.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use giter8 directly you just need to refer to your local template with the `file://` prefix:

```
g8 file://play-scala-seed
```

As mentioned by @volia17, you can find it in the giter8 documentation: [Testing templates locally](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/testing.html).

But when you use `sbt new`, you need you template name (folder) to end with `.g8`. sbt can accept different types of templates and this way it knows that this is a giter8 template. So you can rename your template folder to `play-scala-seed.g8`:

```
sbt new file://play-scala-seed.g8
```

---

P.S. Using giter8 directly is much faster, because `sbt new` takes time to start (it loads global sbt plugins every time).